# Binomial and Poisson Distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

$1$) If $X$, $Y$ are independent Binomial random variables with parameters $(n, p)$ and $(m, p)$, respectively, then $X+Y \sim Binomial(n+m, p)$.

$2$) If $X$,$Y$ are independent Poisson random variables with parameters $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$,respectively, then $X+Y \sim  Poisson (\lambda_1+\lambda_2)$.

How can I prove these with examples ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hints:

Note that a $\text{Binomial}(n,p)$ random variable is the sum of $n$ independent $\text{Bernoulli}(p)$ random variables. From this fact, 1) should be easy to prove.

For 2), you have to get your hands dirty and compute the convolution $P(X+Y=k)=\sum_{i=0}^k P(X=i) P(Y=k-i)$. You can find this on this website and elsewhere.

Comment: I have to show by numbers !!
I calculated the probabilities of: X with (n,p), Y with (m,p) and Z (n+m,p), then how can i prove?

Comment: @yarub Use the convolution, if you must, $\mathsf P(X+Y=z) = \sum_{x=\max(0, z-n)}^{\min(z, n)}\mathsf P(X=x)\mathsf P(Y=z-x)$

Comment: OK Did it !!
Thanks a lot for your explanation